# problem in passing value from jsp to struts2 action

Tags: java, struts2

**In my Action Class,**

```
    private int userId;

    public int getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(int userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }
```

**In my JSP page,**

```
<s:select key="sessionLog.userid" id="userId" name="userId"list="userList" listKey="userId" listValue="username" headerKey="0" headerValue="All Users"/>
```

First, I populate the select box with names of userlist. So, if one user name is selected , I should get the selected userId back in my Action class. But, whenever I selected one user name, I always get 0. how to map ?

but if I only pass userId from javascript, I can get the value. I think in struts, it should automatically map the value. Anything wrong with coding? I want the value from action class.

Thanks.

Comment: What does the HTML render as?

Comment: HTML render as <select name="userId" id="userId">
    <option value="0"
    selected="selected"
    >All Users</option>
    <option value="1">admin</option>
    <option value="6">userA</option>
    <option value="7">userB</option> 
</select>

Comment: I don't know why it always reset back to 0.

Comment: Now I am just trying to pss the value from javascript.

Comment: Please provide full code of the `Action Class` and `User`.

Answer (score 1):

Your action class looks fine. I would suggest however slimming down your select tag to the bare essentials and adding a property tag to the page temporarily to see what, if anything is coming back from your action class. For example, your jsp page should look like this:

```
Selected User ID: <s:property value="userId" />

<s:select name="userId" list="userList" listKey="userId" listValue="username" />
```

It may not make a difference but I've had this cause problems for me - I noticed there is no space between your name attribute and the list attribute in your select tag.

```
name="userId"list="userList" // Should be -->  name="userId" list="userList"
```